# Installing gcc-5.3.0 from source on rhel

Tags: linux, gcc, cross-compiling, rhel

I am using RHEL 6. I would like to install gcc 5.3.0 (gcc-5.3.0.tar.gz) from source. I've already installed GMP, MPC, & MPFR.

How would I approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) read the `README` file.

2) read the `INSTALL` file.

3) follow the instructions there.

The building process of gcc is a three or four stages process to ensure proper compilation, as it initially needs your native compiler to create a proper compiler version that finally has to be autocompiled with the proper compiler to be complete.  This makes the compiler to be compiled first with your native compiler, then it uses the result program to compile itself completely, an produce a controlled copy of the compiler.  Then a new compiler is compiled with the result to produce a complete compiler that is compiled again to produce the final autocompiled compiler (that should be identical to the previous stage)

This is a very complex process that will maintain your machine busy for a while.  Fortunately, everything is explained in the doc files (and most probably better than here)

Comment: There were no steps in the README file. There is an INSTALL directory with build.html, configure.html along with a few others. Even after going through and starting the compiling process i am getting errors.                               make[2]: *** [configure-stage1-target-libgcc] Error1 .   After checking the yum repo it shows libgcc is actually installed.

Answer (score -1):

An easy way to do this is to install gcc5.3 w/ Red Hat Developer Toolset 4.1 (DTS). DTS installs along side the original gcc to avoid collisions.

See https://developers.redhat.com/products/developertoolset/updates/

It's still a yum install, but you must set up/enable software collections first. See an example here: https://developers.redhat.com/products/developertoolset/hello-world/#fndtn-rhel-6

Comment: He is looking for installation via compile from source